# How can i add an image in html email from lotus domino agent?

Tags: html, email, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, agent

i want to add a simple image into an email which i want to send from a lotus agent.

I paste below a part of the code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("<div><img src=\"http://goo.gl/lziMZN\"></div>");
email.setHTMLPart(sb.toString());
email.send("mail@mail.com");
```

I also tried to use an image from my image resources in the nsf.

Whatever i tried i get an empty image area (browser-no-image icon) in the email i receive.
I also have checked "Allow restricted operations" in my agent.

I would prefer it if there is a solution to use an image from my resources and not an external link.

Any solutions?

UPDATE: this is the link for the xpHTMLMail class  http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=create-html-mails-in-ssjs-using-mime

Comment: You could improve this question by explaining more about the email object.  For example, what class is it?  How is it initialized?  I ask because I don't recognized the setHTMLPart method.  Also, have you tried to use the lotus.domino.MIMEEntity class?  That's generally how you work with MIME messages in Notes/Domino.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  In summary, you are using server side JavaScript (SSJS) and a class from the XSnippets project on OpenNTF.  Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with that class and I don't have the bandwidth to research the problem.  Hopefully someone else will answer soon.  If not, I suggest you dig into the MIMEEntity class yourself.  The xpHTMLMail class is using MIMEEntity.  So you can use that as a guide and search StackOverflow for other answers that refer to MIMEEntity.